Is it wise for a Production Browser App to Access Localhost Server

I'm looking at doing something like this:
Browser <-> Desktop App <-> SQLite DB
My first thought was, this opens potential access to that SQLite db to every web app that the user interacts with.
But, if the desktop and browser app connection was secured by a shared key, this would limit access to the desktop api to only those applications the user intended to share that data with.
Is this feasible in a production environment? What might I be overlooking? Primarily concerned that there are security issues I'm opening up.

... Are you just asking us to confirm whether a production server is really just a computer like your local machine is? Because that's the "truth" that you're "uncovering" here.

Genuine question. I'll reword my post

@Flater After rereading your comment, are you essentially saying I'm overthinking it and I can just apply what I do to secure connections to other APIs here?

What is it you believe to be different/special about your local machine that doesn't already apply to a "server" that you would otherwise host your production environment on?

A design like this is occasionally used and can have legitimate uses, but requests from third party websites into the users LAN or localhost are almost always malicious fingerprinting or vulnerability scanning. Currently, browsers tend to allow this by default (with the usual CORS protections), but tracking blockers (e.g. uBlock Origin, AdGuard) should block this: https://github.com/easylist/easylist/issues/19041

@Flater I know that the browser can treat localhost differently than other servers and wasn't sure to what extent that was the case, or if there were other considerations I was missing. Sounds like I'm overthinking it

Good to know @amon, that's very helpful. I'll need to make sure I address that with the UX


But, if the desktop and browser app connection was secured by a shared key, this would limit access to the desktop api to only those applications the user intended to share that data with.

No - it would limit access to everyone that key was shared with. So - how is that key shared?? If it is hardcoded into the desktop application, it is effectively shared with everyone who gets a copy of that application's installer.
The best way I can think of to do this securely would be:

For every user account of the browser app, generate an individual random key
when the browser app first contacts the local API, it calls an initialization endpoint which receives the key and stores it locally

I'll leave it as an execise to the reader to extend this idea to support multiple desktops per user and multiple user accounts being used from the same desktop.

Thank you @Michael, this is very helpful!

This design has mostly the same security risk profile as a web app, web server, and database. The difference is all three components run on a single host. In situations like this, terms like "wise" do not give us any meaningful context to judge the design. Instead, consider this architecture semantically the same as traditional client-server architecture, and along with it comes all the security issues that client-server architecture brings. The only advantage this design has is traffic originating from the public internet should be blocked by firewall rules in your organization or ISP router/cable modem. If the IP address that machine is running on is publically available, then it is wide open to attack just like any other public web server.
There is nothing inherently wrong with this architecture, if that is what the application requires. The challenge is thinking through the security implications and applying authentication and authorization to each component as if the desktop app API were hosted on some remote server, and the database were hosted on its own server. Some additional reading:

Zero trust security model
Zero trust architecture


thank you for sharing the reasoning here. Helps me zoom out from my little world and see the bigger picture

If you hardcode localhost in your software (whatever it is) it will ALWAYS try to contact something on the machine it's running at.
If that's what you intent to do (like in your example running a local SQLite instance for the app to use) that's fine. If you expect the app to contact some remote database you host somewhere out there on the internet, that's of course not going to work and you'll need to supply an actual URI.
So yes, at times it can make perfect sense to use localhost, at other times it makes no sense at all. But if you do use it, make sure that the service you're trying to access is actually running locally on the machine you're trying to access it from, obviously, just as you'd have to make sure the remote service is accessible and available in case you use that.

Thank you @jwenting!
